# Can't send Swift_Message using RabbitMQ and Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, swiftmailer

I'm using the [RabbitMQBundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle) to integrate RabbitMQ into my symfony2 project. Everything works fine (I can produce and consume messages). However, whenever I try to send an email using a Swift_Message from a consumer, I never receive the email. Using `mail('foo@bar.com', 'subject', 'message');` from the consumer does work though.

Here's the code I use to send the Swift_Message:

```
 $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject($subject)
    ->setFrom('noreply@bar.com')
    ->setTo('foo@bar.com')
    ->setBody('Foo Bar');

  $this->container->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

This code works from within a "normal" controller or service. However, it doesn't work when triggered in a consumer by RabbitMQ.

Any got a clue?

Comment: Hi, could you please explain how you get a reference to the container in your consumer?

Comment: You can use `@service_container` as an argument for your service (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container). However, you are better off injecting the proper service, which is the mailer in my case. You can inject it with `@mailer`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should disable swiftmailer's spool feature: remove the `spool` of the swiftmailer bundle configuration.

Get from

```
swiftmailer:
    # ...
    spool: { type: memory }
```

to

```
swiftmailer:
    # ...
```

You can read more about this feature [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html).